# Vector problem: plane set to head due east but is being pushed off course by a crosswind blowing south.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

Problem: A plane is set to head due east at $300$mph, but it is being pushed off course by a crosswind blowing south at $60$mph. At 9AM the plane is located at point $A(10,70)$ and at 10AM the plane is located at point $C(310,10)$.At what direction and speed is the plane traveling?

Attempt:

What I know:

velocity of plane + velocity of the wind = actual speed of the plane

Vector $C$ seems to be the sum of vector $A$ affected by the wind.

$(10+300,70-60)=(310,10)$

Therefore, I think I need to find the magnitude and direction of vector $C$.